# Why are cold liquids rarely called soup (n)?

Tags: word-usage

A friend recently asked me a question for which I couldn't find an answer. 
She said that *soup* (n.) should not be used to describe cold "soups" (ex: like gazpacho or vichyssoise); that these should be called juices and the word soup should be reserved for warm liquids.

I thought this was ludicrous, but when I went to look at the etymology of soup, I couldn't find anything to dissuade her. Can you help?

Merriam-Webster defines *soup* as "[liquid food"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soup), and *gazpacho* as "[spicy soup served cold](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gazpacho)". *Juice* is defined as "[the liquid part that can be squeezed out of vegetables and fruits](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/juice)."

Comment: The meaning of a word [does not necessarily relate to its origin](http://www.economist.com/blogs/johnson/2011/08/word-origins-and-meaning). Since *gazpacho* is very often described as a *chilled soup* or *cold soup*, however, you may surmise that *soup* is accurate, but  that most English-speakers will assume a *soup* is served hot unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Do you want to know if a cold soup is still a soup or if the the two dishes you mention are 'soups'?

Comment: Thanks all--the definition of soup simply comes as "liquid food,"   and yes, as @choster said, "most English-speakers will assume a soup is served hot unless otherwise specified." I was just curious about where the linguistic line for juice or smoothie ends and soup begins. This is really just a passing curiosity and perhaps doesn't belong on this board. Should I delete it?

Comment: good god. I looked at MW and it said liquid food. I looked up gazpacho and it said cold soup. I'll rephrase the question. knuckles sufficiently slapped.

Comment: Why? Because most cold liquids are **not** soup. The same is true of most warm, hot, and lukewarm liquids. Liquids **in general** *are rarely called soup*.

Answer (score 2):

Taking chaslyfromUK's excellent advice to add this comment as an answer because comments are not always permanent...

A food that is called "soup" does not require it to be cooked first or served warm or even with a spoon to fit the category of "soup".

Juices and smoothies are beverages.  Soup is a food that typically takes its place at a certain place in a multi-course meal (before the main course in some cultures or at the end of the meal in other cultures) or can be a stand-alone food, but it is definitely not a beverage.

[Vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/soup) has a serviceable definition that allows for other variations without excluding ones that don't fit a rigid definition:

> 1. n. liquid food especially of meat or fish or vegetable stock often containing pieces of solid food

What I take away from this definition is that soup is a "liquid food".  Regardless of it's preparation method, ingredients or serving temperature, soup can be anything so named that fits the definition of liquid food (and my additional definition..."that is not a beverage".)

Comment: The only difference between a spinach and potato smoothie and cold spinach and potato soup is actually whether you think of it as a beverage or as food. You can make a large vat of it in your blender, pour part of it into a glass and drink it as a smoothie, and then serve the rest in a bowl as a soup for dinner. Exact same liquid; only the context it’s served in distinguishes whether it’s a juice/smoothie or a soup.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet This could be the basis for an interesting experiment.  Serve two bowls of chicken noodle soup: one cold, one hot, and then ask questions about them in ways that would prompt people's ideas about whether a soup should be hot or cold.

Answer (score 1):

> You describe someone's idea that: "the word soup should be reserved
>   for warm liquids."

This seems an odd restriction. Suppose I buy a can of soup. Heat it. Consume some. Put some in the fridge for later. It starts cold, becomes hot, becomes warm, becomes cold again.

If it is soup only during the warm phase, what should I call it the rest of the time? Also, at what precise temperature does the cold 'stuff' transmogrify into 'soup'?  It would certainly be possible to define the upper and lower temperatures but no-one is going to do that in real life.

Speaking personally, I enjoy tomato soup poured from a can into a mug and consumed cold - even with ice on a hot day. Should I change the name?

I would not call it tomato *juice* because that, to me, is the result of removing the liquid element from tomatoes with no additives (except perhaps some salt). By contrast, tomato soup often contains thickening agents as well as other extra ingredients - also it has been *cooked* at some point.

**Final thought**

I believe the chief distinction between soup and juice is that the former has been *cooked* at some point even it is now cold. Cooking makes a chemical change that does not happen with juice.

Comment: Perhaps it is used for liquids usually eaten with a spoon.

Comment: @MRS30 - I cannot agree with that. Suppose there are two people sitting at a table. One always puts the liquid in a bowl and uses a spoon. The other always pours it into a mug and drinks it. It is the same substance in both cases - is it soup for one person but not for the other?

Comment: Soup is part of a meal, generally. One _eats_ soup; one doesn't normally _drink_ it.  Soup can be of any temperature, as long as it's liquid and edible; but most cold liquids are drunk rather than eaten: milk, pop, iced tea, water, juice, etc.

Comment: Kosher dietary rules break it down as such:  https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/mon_10_15_12/

Comment: I think the difference is that Juice is liquid directly from the fruit or vegetable where soup is a combination of liquids or a liquid derived from a process (such a broth).

Comment: Sorry, @chaslyfromUK but as counter-intuitive as it may seem, not all soups are cooked.  I found this recipe for Mango Cucumber soup that is prepared, chilled and served, all without ever being cooked: http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/chilled-mango-and-cucumber-soup-106879

Comment: @KristinaLopez - In that case I would agree with the OP's friend that it is not soup. Unless of course the cooking is done by a process other than heat.

Comment: To your other example regarding a can of soup that has been heated and then cools off - it would still be considered "soup", though not presently at its serving temperature - a concept that is important when discussing a versatile food such as soup.

Comment: @KristinaLopez  I think I already covered that point in my answer. I was specifically answering the part of the original question that defined soup according to temperature.

Comment: OP's friend is not correct - it's soup even though it's never "cooked".  Juice and smoothies are beverages, soup is a food that typically takes its place at a certain place in a multi-course meal or is a stand-alone food but it is definitely not a beverage.

Comment: I think it would be useful if you put that in an answer. That way this does not become a discussion and people can choose which answer(s) they prefer.

Comment: Oops - I confused your opening line of your answer with your answer...you were quoting the OP. :-)

Comment: @JohnLawler This reminds me of a late night game of Scattergories in which the category was "Breakfast food," and the letter was "R."  Someone said "Raspberry smoothie."  We're still arguing about this 10 years later.